# Android studio doesn't check spelling of short words

Tags: android, android-studio, spell-checking

I have a strange problem: Android studio's (Flamingo | 2022.2.1) spell check seems to ignore words that are 3 or less letters long. This happens in comments as well as in code (variable names etc.) - see images. Does anyone know if this can be fixed? I need at least words 2 and 3 letters long to be checked.

Images:

[in comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m19g6.png)

[in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb20y.png)

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not a bug. What you want is not possible in principle. How is Android supposed to know whether `k` is a typo or not? Android would have to look into my brain to determine whether I really meant to type `k` or something else... You can only decide whether you've made a typo after about 4 letters.

The only thing you can do is add individual words (or a private dictionary) in `Settings>Editor>Spelling`, which Android Studio does not yet know and therefore still marks as typos.

Comment: Thanks, but I asked about words 2 and 3 letters long. Common text editors (MS Word, Google docs) do check such words, so it's not impossible. Maybe there is a separate plugin or standalone tool to check typos in all my comments?

Comment: @Andrey Korolev: Same answer for words with 2 or 3 letters. You must define when a word is misspelled. Usual definition is when it is not in any dictionary of this world. Or, quite equivalently, when Google Search doesn't return a hit for that word. But I bet you that you won't find a 2 or 3 letter word that Google doesn't have a match for.

Comment: @Andrey Korolev: Android Studio is not a word processing program, and it does not know what your native language is (whereas Word etc. does). It therefore cannot perform a deeper text analysis. Thus Android Studio simply compares all typed words with the built-in dictionary (which obviously does not contain words with less than 4 letters for the reasons mentioned above).